# How can I fill my density chart with 2 factors in with shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, heatmap

In my first panel, I have plot where I enter data by clicking or double clinking depending on the situation. If it's one click it categorized as a shot and if it's a double click it is categorized as a goal.

Simultaneously, on another Tab, I am creating a heat map of all of those shots. However, in my heat map (produced in my code in output$chart) I would like to have two different colours on the same heat map. One colour representing the shots and the other one representing the goal.

Thank you for your help

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hockey"),
  tags$img(height = 100, width = 100,
           src = "Logo.png"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput(inputId = "date",
              label = "Date", 
              value = "yyyy/mm/dd"),
    textInput(inputId = "team",
              label = "Team Name", 
              value = "Team Name"),
    selectInput("shot", "shot type:",
                list(`Shot Type` = list("wrist shot", "slap shot", "snap shot", "backhand", "tap in", "deflection", "one timer", "wrap around"))),
    actionButton("reset", "Clear")),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Track", plotOutput(outputId = "hockeyplot", click = "plot_click", dblclick = "plot_dblclick")),
    tabPanel("Chart", plotOutput(outputId = "chart")),
   

server <- function(input, output){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    df = data.frame(
      x = numeric(),
      y = numeric(),
      Date = as.Date(character()),
      Team = character(),
      ShotType = character(),
      Type = factor()
    )
  )
  
  output$hockeyplot = renderPlot({ 
    ggplot(rv$df,
           aes(x = x, y = y)) + coord_flip() + lims(x = c(0, 100), y = c(42.5, -42.5)) + geom_blank + geom_point( aes(colour = factor(Type)), size = 5 ) + theme(legend.position = "none")})
  
  
   observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    rv$df <- rbind(rv$df, data.frame(
      x = input$plot_click$y,
      y = input$plot_click$x,
      Date = input$date, 
      Team = input$team, 
      ShotType = input$shot, 
      Type = "Shot"))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_dblclick, {
    rv$df <- rbind(rv$df, data.frame(
      x = input$plot_dblclick$y,
      y = input$plot_dblclick$x,
      Date = input$date, 
      Team = input$team,  
      ShotType = input$shot, 
      Type = "Goal"))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    rv$df <- rv$df[-nrow(rv$df),]
  })
  

  
  output$chart = renderPlot({
    ggplot(rv$df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
      coord_flip()+
      lims(x = c(0, 100), y = c(42.5, -42.5)) +
      geom_blank+
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      stat_density_2d(aes(fill = "shot"), geom = 'polygon', alpha = 0.4) 
  })
```

Comment: Where is `gg_rink` from?

Comment: It is a separate function, to make easier and less complicated, I just replaced the gg_rink by geom_blank, which does the same principle. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example.

I created a vector `my_colors` to assign colors to "Shot" and "Goal" so they are consistent across figures, and will not change if `Type` factor has different number of levels.

I also included `factor` when adding rows to your `rv$df`. That way, you also won't have a change in color as the number of levels change for `Type`. When I tried running the app initially, the colors would change after a second `Type` was added ("Shot" or "Goal").

In `stat_2_density`, you can change `fill` to `Type`. Again, you can specify `scale_fill_manual` to assign the same colors.

Please let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

my_colours = c("Shot" = "blue", "Goal" = "green")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hockey"),
  tags$img(height = 100, width = 100, src = "Logo.png"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput(inputId = "date",
              label = "Date", 
              value = "yyyy/mm/dd"),
    textInput(inputId = "team",
              label = "Team Name", 
              value = "Team Name"),
    selectInput("shot", "shot type:",
                list(`Shot Type` = list("wrist shot", "slap shot", "snap shot", "backhand", "tap in", "deflection", "one timer", "wrap around"))),
    actionButton("reset", "Clear")),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Track", plotOutput(outputId = "hockeyplot", click = "plot_click", dblclick = "plot_dblclick")),
    tabPanel("Chart", plotOutput(outputId = "chart"))
  ))
)
    
    
server <- function(input, output){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    df = data.frame(
      x = numeric(),
      y = numeric(),
      Date = as.Date(character()),
      Team = character(),
      ShotType = character(),
      Type = factor(levels = c("Shot", "Goal"))
    )
  )
  
  output$hockeyplot = renderPlot({ 
    ggplot(rv$df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
      coord_flip() + 
      lims(x = c(0, 100), y = c(42.5, -42.5)) + 
      geom_blank() + 
      geom_point(aes(color = Type), size = 5 ) + 
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      scale_color_manual(values = my_colours)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    rv$df <- rbind(rv$df, data.frame(
      x = input$plot_click$y,
      y = input$plot_click$x,
      Date = input$date, 
      Team = input$team, 
      ShotType = input$shot, 
      Type = factor("Shot", levels = c("Shot", "Goal"))))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_dblclick, {
    rv$df <- rbind(rv$df, data.frame(
      x = input$plot_dblclick$y,
      y = input$plot_dblclick$x,
      Date = input$date, 
      Team = input$team,  
      ShotType = input$shot, 
      Type = factor("Goal", levels = c("Shot", "Goal"))))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    rv$df <- rv$df[-nrow(rv$df),]
  })
  
  output$chart = renderPlot({
    ggplot(rv$df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
      coord_flip()+
      lims(x = c(0, 100), y = c(42.5, -42.5)) +
      geom_blank()+
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      stat_density_2d(aes(fill = Type), geom = 'polygon', alpha = .4) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = my_colours)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Exactly. Thank you Ben for your help